# How to avoid typing username and password again and again when using egit in eclipse on mac air?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

The authorize dialog popup again and again and again when i try to push or pull, even if i checked the "store in secure store" checkbox.

Some guys said: Open Git repositories view, open "Remotes > origin > " and click "Change Credentials...", but it didn't work either.

thanks!

Comment: The problem has bean solved finally. I downloaded a new eclipse, installed egit plugin and re-ran the push command. After i typed the username and password,  a new dialog popped up and asked me if this access to eclipse's "secure store" could be trusted, then you know, i clicked "always trust" ......

Comment: If you do not gain the access permission, you will find its empty in "preferences->general->security->secure storage->contents->Git".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Credential Helpers](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Permanently+authenticating+with+Git+repositories#PermanentlyauthenticatingwithGitrepositories-Usingcredentialcaching) or [.netrc](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Permanently+authenticating+with+Git+repositories#PermanentlyauthenticatingwithGitrepositories-Usingthe.netrcfile) file or directly use [password in URL](http://forjavaprogrammers.blogspot.in/2012/07/git-save-username-and-password.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a problem caused by eclipse's access system.